# Can't boot into Ubuntu 13.04 64 Bit

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, 13.04

I just freshly installed Ubuntu 13.04 64Bit using a bootable usb. After installing I click restart and my laptop boots into windows 7 without asking me to select OS. My boot menu is a traditional one does not have Secure boot or UEFI options.

Comment: when booting hold down shift key until u see boot menu

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: did you noticed installing  ...in end it install grub before it ask to restart

Comment: Yes. I did. I saw installing grub2.

Comment: ok boot again from usb as GM-Scrip.. saying and reinstall grub

Comment: Do you see the ubuntu boot screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I solved the problem. I re-installed the grub from my USB stick with -

```
~$ sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt (sdaX is where ubuntu is installed)
~$ sudo install-grub --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring up your boot-menu on your laptop BIOS and select your flash drive if the laptop support it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the MBR was installed to the usb drive, in which case you will find out doing what Andrew said really fast (boot your flash drive like you did when you installed ubuntu)

You will need to run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` I assume you HDD is `sda` and your flash drive is `sdb`

If someone could tell me how to reply instead of answer that would be helpful (i only see the option for my own answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:
- Boot using your Ubuntu USB -> Try ubuntu
- Install boot-repair
- Reboot. You should see the OS list.